# substituição com expressão regular - referência seguida de número

Tags: regex

#### Situação

Estava realizando um replace da alguns dados quando me deparei com uma peculiaridade.

```
|C405|01102015|7|1058|174544|19836903,14|18657,06|
|C405|02102015|2|1059|174792|19859872,19|22441,55|
|C405|03102015|3|1060|174953|19872892,09|12993,90|
|C405|05102015|5|1061|175186|19893103,21|20126,12|
|C405|06102015|3|1062|175409|19914579,78|20500,57|
|C405|07102015|7|1063|175616|19937968,35|23388,57|
|C405|08102015|2|1064|175800|19954350,96|16382,61|
|C405|09102015|1|1065|176034|19975441,21|20483,75|
|C405|10102015|7|1066|176189|19987132,54|11570,33|
|C405|13102015|2|1067|176422|20010561,52|23052,98|
|C405|14102015|3|1068|176629|20033609,96|23020,44|
|C405|15102015|5|1069|176809|20054577,77|20885,81|
|C405|16102015|1|1070|177020|20077339,30|22456,53|
```

Ao montar esta `regex` :

```
pattern : (\|C405\|\d+\|)\d
replace : $13
```

Aqui eu tenho um erro, pois meu intuito é fazer o replace do grupo 1 e apos inserir o literal 3, mas o mesmo esta interpretando como grupo 13, que não existe. E mesmo que eu altere o replace para `$1\3`, o editor tenta capturar o grupo 1 e o grupo 3, pois interpreta tanto `${digito}` e `\{digito}` como retrovisores.

A Solução para este problema especifico é bem simples :

```
pattern : (\|C405\|\d+)\|\d
replace : $1\|3
```

#### Questão

Digamos que eu não tenha esta solição, que eu deva capturar um grupo e em seguita inserir um *digito*, como inserir **NADA**, no meio dos termos?
`$1{NADA}3`

#### Obs

Sem realizar duas operações de REGEX:

```
pattern : (\|C405\|\d+\|)\d
replace : $1\x023

pattern : \x02
replace :
```

Comment: `\13` resolve o seu problema?

Comment: @rray simples assim? sim resolveu, isso se deve ao fato do `\{digito}` ir de `\1...\9` correto? então o segundo digito seria considerado literal. Mas como seria a solução caso o grupo de replace for `$12` por exemplo?

Comment: `$12\3`, grupo 12 seguido do número 3 seria isso?

Comment: @rray ai não funciona, pois `\3` é um retrovisor, como expliquei, então ele tenta substituir pelo grupo 3. E manter $123 também não funciona, pois ele interpretara como grupo 123.

Comment: Não sei se está usando alguma linguagem ou se é apenas um replace com algum editor de texto, com a linguagem, a primeira coisa que me passa pela cabeça é fazer um replace arbitrario apenas na 12ª ocorrência. Vou procurar mais alguma coisa.

Comment: @rray eu estou usando o *Sublime* para o mesmo, mas se for `PHP` seria a mesma coisa, creio que `Python` também, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @MarcosRegis eu fiz o texte do PHP com `preg_replace('~(\|C405\|\d+\|)\d~', '$13', $string)` e ele me cortou todo o `pattern` assim como não inseriu o *3*.
[sublime](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text). é C++

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Removi meu comentario pq realmente em algumas engines ele gera um grupo vazio quando se tentar utilizar um agrupamento não existente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta curta: depende da implementação.

No editor *gedit* ([sintaxe Python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16746/64211)) foi aceito como substituição: `\g<1>3`.

No *Netbeans* (que é feito em Java) a substituição foi feita correta com `$1\2`, escapando o número seguinte.

No editor *sublime* e no *geany* a substituição foi feita como esperado com `\13` pois as referências vão de 0 a 9.

Em PHP a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) aponta o uso de chaves: `${1}3`. O `sublime` também aceita essa sintaxe (conforme apontado pelo @GuilhermeLautert).

Em Javascript a substituição com `$13` funciona, desde que não exista um grupo de número 13.

Comment: Sua referencia para `${{digito}}` funcionou, tanto em PHP quanto no sublime.

Answer (score 1):

Para a questão de inserir um NADA dá pra fazer assim

```
pattern : ((?:))(\|C405\|\d+)\|\d
replace : $2\13
```

Repare que usei \1 para o replace ao invés de $1.
O Agrupamento vazio funcionou em todos os engines REGEX que testei, porém o uso de $ ou \ pode variar de engine para engine.

Em Javascript já não funciona item acima mas dá pra colocar um caractere nulo (ex.: \x01) que não é adicionado a string final.

```
var a = "0000111222333444555666777888999";
a.replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d+)/g,"$1\x013");
```

Comment: Realmente não tinha pensado nesta lógica de chamar um grupo sem captura. Em JS poderia ser assim `var a = "123456789"; a.replace(/()(\d+)/g,"$2$13");`, se aproveitando do contexto que o @sanção comentou sobre não existir o grupo 13.